# Menu, launchpad and windows disappeared

Tags: unity, drivers, ati, graphics

On my fresh installed Ubuntu, I ran the things described in [this list](http://howtoubuntu.org/things-to-do-after-installing-ubuntu-12-04-precise-pangolin#.Uq42TWTuIf8), more precisely the last part installing a bunch of softwares, when all the unity layout disappeard.

There was:

- No launchpad
- No menu bar
- Windows were only with their bare content
- alt-tab and other commands of this kind were not responding

In the end I hard-reboot my computer, restarted, and:

It looked like my graphic cards driver was not there anymore (steam saying I only have 250mb of dedicated GPU memory, simple 2D game being suddenly slow) so I assumed something made my graphic driver wrong.
I have a ATI Radeon HD 6800, so I went to AMD's website and installed their last drivers, then rebooted.

Then:

- At boot, a message (which I don't have the time to see exactly) tells me it desactivated tty (I guess it's a video driver problem?)
- For a second, the desktop appears correctly, but then everything disappears as said before.
- I try to access the terminal but can't (tty desactivated). I actually can't do anything else than clicking arround. Right clicking and openning the desktop customization menu works though.
- Now I can't really do anything, not even access a terminal, so I don't know how to unstuck this...

Comment: If tty & terminal are 'deactivated' then copying the stuff and doing a fresh install may be the only thing... You should be able to load up an Ubuntu installation media, copy any stuff you want off it to a USB stick or something using that, and then do a fresh install from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I just thought of unplugging my second monitor and retry:

This time the system managed to boot and work. I re-replugged my monitor, rebooted again, and had mirror displays and my driver alerting me that I need to configure my displays for higher res.

Went back to the driver, put back my old configuration and all was working like before. I still have to reboot to be sure it stays but, well.

I still have the desactivation of tty at boot though. Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: You should gather more information about the TTY issue and ask a new question about it.

Comment: You're probably right. But it seems that these problems are linked, so I precised it just in case it's relevant.